# Configure nginx temporary proxy cache dir?

Tags: nginx

Running strace on nginx running as a caching reverse proxy server, I can see that it creates cache files in /var/lib/nginx/proxy and then moves them to my configured proxy_cache_path.

Is there any way to make it write cache files directory to my configured directory, or is it possible to change the temporary directory cache path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible using `proxy_temp_path` configuration setting ([here's the reference](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_temp_path)).

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the temporary location like this:

```
proxy_cache_path /path/to/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m use_temp_path=off;

server {
    # ...
    location / {
        proxy_cache my_cache;
        proxy_pass http://my_upstream;
    }
}
```

Taken from the official nginx website: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/#How-to-Set-Up-and-Configure-Basic-Caching